# Python3: Static checking typing.Protocol class implementation

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I want to use **typing.Protocol** to make interfaces in my code but there is a little broblem.

PEP 544 scribes *"Also, extensive use of ABCs might impose additional runtime costs."*

So if a class will not be notated as an implementation of some Protocol then it will take much more time for code inspection in the future and no static type checking. I found only 1 way to make such a "notation" via the class inheritance semantics. But inheritation makes just a standard ABC instance from a Protocol and adds some runtime cost.

Is there an existing way for leaving this explicit notation only for static type checking but not for runtime?

May be something like this:

```
...
@implements(MyProtocol)
class MyImplClass:
...
```

Comment: I don't understand what @implements should do. Adding any missing MyProtocol methods? Or what else?

Comment: It should only say to living programmer and to mypy that there must be MyProtocol methods.

Comment: Mypy does not need it. The living programmer can read doc.

Comment: All this you could said about typing.Protocol some years ago.

Comment: You are saying that today, for example, every Iterator should be marked with an Iterator Protocol?